# Determine source that inserted record

Tags: sql-server

My Sql Server skills are a little rusty, I have a table that has an on insert trigger and processes data/records when records are inserted into the table.  I need to be able to identify the source of this inserted record, IE; were they inserted by program A, or a stored procedure or some other process.  I cannot change the structure of the database other than to add/modify the trigger.  There are various tricks/methods running through my mind but looking for best practices based from people with more experience than I.  Thank you.

Comment: There's `APP_NAME` if the callers remember to set it to something meaningful, `SESSION_CONTEXT()` and `CONTEXT_INFO()` for explicit handshakes between callers "in the know" , and you can look at `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_connections` using `@@SPID` for more intricate analysis of where things come from. Direct access to the T-SQL execution stack is not provided.

Comment: Even if you can tell who it is you have no way of knowing how it was executed. Meaning that you can probably tell that it was "program A" (if the connection string has application name set, or a few other tricks mentioned above). But you have no way of knowing inside your trigger if that was fired because a stored procedure was called or if there was an ad hoc query executed.

Comment: @SeanLange: `SESSION_CONTEXT()` and (in earlier versions) `CONTEXT_INFO()` can be used for that, by setting a magic cookie in the stored procedure that the ad-hoc query will not (know how to) set and using it in the trigger. Of course, triggers are hard enough to maintain without throwing in secret handshakes like this, but sometimes it's the best you can do without access to callers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was going on the assumption that the stored proc wouldn't change since the OP stated they cannot change anything other than adding a trigger. But I totally agree it would work although rather kludgey. ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions, I will investigate each one carefully.  Out of the gate I'm leaning towards `APP_NAME`, perhaps I can assume that if it's null or empty, that the insert came from something other than what I'm looking for.  Obviously further investigation is required though, especially in the context of the app/process..